# /usr/bin/env: python2.5: No such file or directory

Tags: python, hadoop

I'm trying to play with Cloudera's Distribution for Hadoop on my EC2 account. For configuring it i'm using [THIS](http://archive.cloudera.com/docs/ec2.html) tutorial. Everything seems to me fine but when I'm trying to run `hadoop-ec2`

I'm getting following error:

```
max@ubuntu:~/Desktop/cloudera-for-hadoop-on-ec2-py-0.3.0-beta$ ./hadoop-ec2 
/usr/bin/env: python2.5: No such file or directory
```

I tried to run **`which env`** got this **`/usr/bin/env`** and there I have these folders: `Python` and `Python2.6`

So, should I rename `Python2.6` to `Python2.5` or there is another way to change fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to install Python 2.5-this SHOULD work-but the best way to find the 2.5 distro is by firing up Aptitude and finding the correct one:

```
apt-get install python2.5
```

As root of course.

Comment: Thanks for "apt-get install python2.5" it works now, thanks

Comment: I agree with Josh, but it is likely that the script will work with Python 2.6, so you could change the shebang line to "#!/usr/bin/env python2.6" or even "#!/usr/bin/env python"